# howto get startActivityForResult within GCM receiver

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcast, google-cloud-messaging

Please help me. I need to get activity result from GCM receiver, the code is below

On MainActivity.class

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      //PARSE RESULT CODE
       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
           Toast.makeText(_context,"WAS LOGIN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           mainProgram();
        }else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
           Toast.makeText(_context,"WAS NOT LOGIN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           showLoginForm();
        }
  }


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(SampleList.THEME); // Used for theme switching in samples
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginProc.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);      
}
private void mainProgram(){
 setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);
}
```

and in LoginProc.class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
     GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
     GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);  
     GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
     registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver,new IntentFilter(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
     this.regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
     GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
}

private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
        WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"New Message On MHandled:"+newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Releasing wake lock
        WakeLocker.release();

        //hide progress
        showProgress(false); 

        //set result vars for this intent
        Intent i=new Intent();
    LoginProc.this.setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
        //Intent i = new Intent();
    //setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, i);
    finish();
    }
};
```

and the result is always show ToastText "WAS NOT LOGIN" even after event GCM is success (Toas "New Message On MHandled" displayer).

Need right direction here, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have given all needed permission and this receives messages via GCMIntentService which would have to register in Manifest.

**Check this** [**link**](http://fundroiding.wordpress.com/2012/06/29/google-cloud-messaging-for-android-gcm-simple-tutorial/)

This will tell the steps for GCM registration and getting push messages from server.